# Dynamically change cursor color to indicate input script

Tags: fonts, colors, cursor, keyboard-layout

I'd like to use the cursor color to provide visual feedback on the alphabet I am currently in (I sometimes have to switch rapidly between, say, Latin and Cyrillic, and find myself typing in the wrong script).

Something like this:

http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2009/12/changing-cursor-color-and-shape.html

But I can't find a good way to detect the keyboard layout (Unicode code page, ...) to tell which language I am in, in order to use that to change the parameters of the cursor.

I am on MacOS, but it would be preferable to have a general solution.

Comment: See [this Emacs Wiki page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ChangingCursorDynamically) and library [`cursor-chg.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/cursor-chg.el) for how to change the cursor depending on the context, including depending on the current input method. But that won't tell you how to detect a given keyboard layout. I doubt there is a way to tell that easily from Emacs, but I could be wrong. Google for `emacs keyboard layout`?